# Redirecting page from form with addEventListener() method

Tags: javascript, onclick, addeventlistener, dom-events, onkeypress

I am trying to get an input value from a form to redirect to the user to a new page. The environment is in Sharepoint Online.

I can't use HTML events (i.e. onclick or onkeypress), which is why I decided to use event listeners instead.

I have tested the code locally and know that it would work with the above-mentioned events, but I was asked to remove them in order to prevent XSS type attacks.

I tried using event listeners but can't seem to get it to work the way I want it should.

HTML code:

```
<form method="get" action="" class="search-container">
      <input id="search-input" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
      <a class="material-icons" id="search-submit" >search</a>
</form>
```

JS code:

```
document.getElementById('search-input').addEventListener('keypress', searchKeyPress)

function searchKeyPress(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  if (e.keyCode === 13)
  {
      document.getElementById('search-submit').click();
      //alert('Enter Pressed')
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}

document.getElementById('search-submit').addEventListener('click', redirect)

// redirect function
function redirect() {
  //look for search id
  var item = document.getElementById("search-input").value;

  // alert(item)

  //redirect page
  alert('Search Icon Clicked')
  window.location.href = "https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/Intranet/_layouts/15/osssearchresults.aspx?u=https%3A%2F%domain%2Esharepoint%2Ecom%2Fsites%2FIntranet&k=" + item + "&ql=1036";

}
```

I expect to be able to redirect to the page that is in the 
`window.location.href`, but the page refreshes instead.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage)

Comment: _“but the page refreshes instead”_ - most likely because you clicked on a _link_, but neglected to suppress the default action in your event handler.

Comment: I tried that, but adding ```e.preventDefault();``` still didn't make it work. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution!

Turns out that the event listener was interpreted as null. To solve it, I made sure that it loaded after the window did.

Adding `e.preventDefault();` for the `Enter` key was also useful.

See below:

```
// Make sure code loads after window loads
window.onload = function(){
    var input = document.getElementById('search-input')
    input.addEventListener('keypress', searchKeyPress);

    var submit = document.getElementById('search-submit')
    submit.addEventListener('click', redirect);
};

//Input Keypress function
function searchKeyPress(e) {
  // event.preventDefault();
  e = e || window.event;

  if (e.keyCode === 13)
  {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById('search-submit').click();
    //alert('Enter Pressed');
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

// redirect function
function redirect() {
  //look for search id
  var item = document.getElementById("search-input").value;

  // alert(item)

  //redirect page
  alert('Search Icon Clicked')
  window.location.href = "https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/Intranet/_layouts/15/osssearchresults.aspx?u=https%3A%2F%domain%2Esharepoint%2Ecom%2Fsites%2FIntranet&k=" + item + "&ql=1036";

}
```